Azure AD OAuth token in ServiceNow (SSO Enabled) without login popup
We have a requirement in ServiceNow where we need to send a bearer token to an external api and the token must contain user assertion (to support OBO flow in the api). The ServiceNow instance is SSO enabled. Is there a way to generate the OAuth token without showing the login or azure ad account selection popup screen to the user?
We created an OAuth Application Registry in ServiceNow of type "Connect to a third party OAuth Provider" as shown below and used this as a OAuth2.0 authentication option in the REST Message used to call the external api.
Application Registry
REST Message
This generate a token with user assertion but only after showing the login popup to the user even when the user is already logged in to the ServiceNow instance using its Azure AD account.

To bypass the login popup and obtain OAuth tokens seamlessly in ServiceNow, ensure proper OAuth 2.0 configuration like username password flow. Utilize server-side token requests with user authentication information passed to Azure AD, ensuring a smooth authentication flow without user interaction.
